# How to change date format in logstash

Tags: logstash

I have a logs like below;

```
04/12/2020 5:12:56 PM
05/12/2020 6:13:36 AM
```

I want to match this fields and change to this format in below;

```
2020-12-04 17:12:56
2020-12-04 06:13:36
```

How can i do this in logstash ?

Thanks for answering

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code gives

```
filter {
      mutate {
         add_field => {"old_time" => "04/12/2020 5:12:56 PM"}
      }

      ruby {
         code => '
              time = Time.parse(event.get("old_time")).strftime("%y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
              event.set("new_time", time)

         '
       }

     mutate {
        remove_field => ["host","@timestamp","sequence","message","@version"]
     } 
 }
```

this output

```
{
   "old_time" => "04/12/2020 5:12:56 PM",
   "new_time" => "20-12-04 17:12:56"
}
```

Comment: if you need `yyyy` change the `%y` to `%Y`. I forgot to put this in the answer.